# NVIDIA product number: how to read it?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hardware, gpu

Though the question seems stupid, I'm ignorant about this; how to read the name of my NVIDIA graphics card?

I used lshw -c display :

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

So the model for my NIVIDIA GForce is "GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M"

But this name is too long ! I want to install the drivers + cuda for my model, but I need to make sense out of the product name I got

Thank you.

Comment: The driver is the same for all these adapters.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you elaborate please ? as I understand; the "adapter" is the graphics card and so I have 2 graphics cards on my system: GForce and Intel's HD Graphics 5500. I didn't understand what you meant by the "driver is the same"

Comment: You are correct that you have two GPUs: Intel and Nvidia. You need drivers only for the Nvidia. And it doesn't matter which one of `610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M` you actually have. When you install a proprietary driver, it will show the model more precisely. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the proprietary drivers, just run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The proprietary Nvidia drivers are included in the default repositories on all newer versions of Ubuntu so there's no need to guess or download the wrong driver from the Nvidia website.